# Is this a typo in an exercise about Hilbert spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

I'm doing an exercise about functional analysis:

> [image: po]
>   [image]

**My questions:**

1. In question 5,

> For every $x \in H,$ justify the existence of a unique vector $T_{x} \in H$ such that for all $y \in K$
>   $$
> \left\|x-T_{x}\right\| \leq\|x-y\|
> $$

Should it be "a unique vector $T_{x} \in K$" rather than "a unique vector $T_{x} \in H$"? In this way, we can apply orthogonal projection on a closed convex set $K$. In the original question, clearly $T_x=x$ satisfies. If $z$ is close to $x$ enough, then $T_x = z$ also satisfies.

Could you please verify if my observation is correct?

2. Please shed me some lights on computing $T_x$ in question 7 and proving $T_{-x}=-T_{x}$ in question 8!

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: At first blush, I would say, "Not necessarily." It looks a lot like a standard result in Fourier analysis: there is an element "closest" to a closed subset.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKeister, but question 5 also mentions the uniqueness.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a typo to me.  Otherwise, unless $x \in K$, we could find a ball of satisfactory $T_x$ around $x$.  Presumably they want you to take $x - \langle x, v \rangle v$.  ETA: Oops, now I see problem 7.

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification @BrianTung? Please shed me some lights on computing $T_x$ in question 7!

Comment: **Hint.** What is the norm of a difference of two vectors?  Such as, say, $x - \langle x, v\rangle v$?

Comment: Hi @BrianTung, After some steps, I got that $\|x - \langle x, v\rangle v\|^2 = \|x\|^2 - \langle x, v\rangle^2$, then I stuck :(((

Comment: Oh, are you supposed to get further than that?  Unless you're told something about $x$ and $v$, I don't think you can, can you?

Comment: Hi @BrianTung, you meant that we can not find the explicit formula of $T_x$ in case  $x \in H\setminus F$? If it is the case, I don't know how to solve the question 8 :(

Comment: You can still solve it, by considering what $(-x) - \langle (-x), v \rangle v$ is, and what its norm is (in the same general terms as we have arrived at for part 7).

Comment: Hi @BrianTung. Honestly, I have tried but to avail in question 6. Could you please give me more specific clues?

Comment: Hi @BrianTung, I've just made an attempt at question 8 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415726/let-t-x-be-the-orthogonal-projection-of-x-on-k-prove-that-t-x-t-x). Could you please have a check on it? Thank you so much for your help!